# Sending data to a TCP Server

Tags: c#, serial-port, tcpclient

I'm trying to realize a program that sends data to a TCP-server and then receives the same message by COM-port. I have the following code but it sends the data but doesn't receive any data.

When I monitor the serial port I can't see that the data is received.

How do I fix this? Do I have to switch to a multi threading system or is there a other way to sync this? Because I can see that the COM-port is opened but not read out.

And when I test this with Putty I can get it to work.

```
public class Variables
{
    private static int v_VarI = 0;

    public static int VarI
    {
        get { return v_VarI; }
        set { v_VarI = value; }
    }

    private static int v_VarJ = 0;

    public static int VarJ
    {
        get { return v_VarJ; }
        set { v_VarJ = value; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public class TcpTimeClient
    {
        private const int portNum = 6666;
        private const string hostName = "192.168.1.51";
        private const string data = "test";

        public static int Main(String[] args)
        {

            new SerialPortProgram();

            while (Variables.VarI < 10)
            {
                Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                try
                {
                    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostName, portNum);

                    NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    ns.Write(bytesSent, 0, bytesSent.Length);
                    int bytesRead = ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                    client.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
                Variables.VarI++;
                while (Variables.VarJ < Variables.VarI)
                {

                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public class SerialPortProgram
    {
        public SerialPort receiveport = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        public SerialPortProgram()
        {
            receiveport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

            receiveport.Open();
        }

        public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
            string rec_data = receiveport.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine(rec_data);
            Variables.VarJ++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
 
 I've found that the program I wrote and putty and an other program named Serial Port Monitor differ in the IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK.

Serial Port Monitor: 0x00 00 01 19
Putty: Unkown
Own program: 0x00 00 01 FB

Does anyone know how to change this mask? Because it's not in the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class.

Comment: Maybe COM port is silent because nobody writes to COM port?

Comment: When I use Putty to connect in raw and serial mode I get it to work.

Comment: so, with putty you verify, that some data are actually transfered through COM when your application make a request to TCP server, ok. Now check your COM port settings (port number, baudrate, parity and flow control) and set breakpoint at `port_DataReceived` handler to verify, that handler actually not invoked.

Comment: I've tried this using a breakpoint with action that prints the received data and it won't get triggered. I've placed it at "string rec_data = receiveport.ReadExisting();"

Comment: then, this should be a configuration issue, since there is nothing special in `SerialPort` itself (I mean, you don't need to do some special initialization to get this events raises).

Comment: oh, just see that you not storing a reference of `new SerialPortProgram();`. Try to assign it to something.

Comment: I have found a problem when i connect with putty I everything just works but when I connect with my program it locks on IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL (IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
         int length =  receiveport.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buf = new byte[length];
        SerialPort2.Read(buf, 0, length);

    }
```

buf array is your answer but in decimal mode . and you can changed it to want.

Answer (score 0):

The wait mask is not your problem. Your wait mask enables the serial port for `RXCHAR RXFLAG CTS DSR RLSD BRK ERR RING` and has everything except ERR turned on.

This is correct for the way .Net wraps serial ports, and anyway it is not exposed in the .NET serial port class. Don't waste time pursuing that difference; your problem lies elsewhere.

Your serial port code ran perfectly on my system and printed all the data received from an external serial source, so I suspect your problem is with the TCP server whose code you did not post, or with your serial ports. Perhaps your configuration requires that you transmit something before the port begins sending? Try something like:

```
            receiveport.Open();
            receiveport.WriteLine("?");
```

Then if you still have problems, try connecting to another serial device to see if you can prove your receive code is working for you as it is for me. If you still can't figure it out, post more information about what's happening on the serial source end.